# Which cable to use from iMac 5k to 30 inch Dell monitor?

Tags: display, imac

I have an iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015) and I'd like to attach to it a 30 inch Dell monitor  3007wfp[t]  at 2560x1600 px DVI input only.

I don't know where to look for if that resolution is supported.

Comment: Yes it's possible but you need to include details like the model of the Dell monitor and what type of connections it supports (DVI, DisplayPort, HDMI, etc.)

Comment: This depends on the specific monitor model and the ports it has.

Comment: hi, it is this bad boy here  3007wfpt and it only accpets DVI

Comment: @patrix I've added specs, please lift hold

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-ultrasharp-3007wfp/review/ probably different market renaming, but same difference

Comment: I'll answer formally when it get's re-opened but I have had this model monitor before and the only adapter I was able to get to work reliably with it was the [Kannex  mDP to DL-DVI](https://tr.im/kannex_mini_displayport_dual_link_dvi).  Give that one a shot

Comment: damn, I'm not sure it's worth to use a cable that costs more than the monitor itself. I'll consider buying a new monitor probably. thanks!

Comment: It's a fantastic monitor for sure (and heavy) but the only downside was that it **only** had a DL-DVI port.  I went through about 5 or 6 different adapters until I found one that worked.  I voted to reopen, but if the question is no longer valid, consider deleting.

Comment: well, yes it's a fantastic monitor and I used it for so many years. I agree it's sad that it only has one DL-DVI port. I don't care much if @patrix doesn't remove the hold status. I think it's informative as it is and I don't care much about karma either

Comment: FYI - anyone with review status can lift the hold. Your edit to the post is what triggers that review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with a dual link dvi adapter if you brought both to me.

- [Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter](http://store.apple.com/xc/product/MB571LL/A)

If you have bought the display, dell support should have a KB article / manual explaining if dual link is needed for the resolution you want. If you haven't bought, make sure the pre-sales support can answer that.

That iMac can drive far higher resolution at 60 Hz:

> single-stream 4K (3840x2160) - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587

You might even get by with single link dvi - it will certainly work, just possibly at lower resolution if your overriding concern is saving $$